# trouble with onboard wifi, usb wifi okay

Tags: wifi, systemd-networkd, iwlwifi

Trouble with onboard wifi.

As this output shows, the Comet Lake wifi is recognized but not assigned a logical name and is not assigned an IP -- although it is configured through systemd-network and does appear sometimes.

What does this mean.

Arch 5.18.16

```
 :> lshw -class network
   *-network:0               
        description: Network controller
        product: Comet Lake PCH-LP CNVi WiFi
        vendor: Intel Corporation
        physical id: 14.3
        bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
        version: 00
        width: 64 bits
        clock: 33MHz
        capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list
        configuration: driver=iwlwifi latency=0
        resources: iomemory:600-5ff irq:16 memory:6023114000-6023117fff
   *-network:1 DISABLED
        description: Ethernet interface
        product: Ethernet Connection (10) I219-V
        vendor: Intel Corporation
        physical id: 1f.6
        bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
        logical name: eno1
        version: 00
        serial: 1c:69:7a:aa:62:20
        capacity: 1Gbit/s
        width: 32 bits
        clock: 33MHz
        capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
        configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=5.18.16-arch1-1 firmware=0.8-4 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
        resources: irq:168 memory:96300000-9631ffff
   *-network
        description: Wireless interface
        physical id: 2
        bus info: usb@1:3
        logical name: wlan0
        serial: 24:05:0f:f6:db:46
        capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
        configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8812au driverversion=v5.13.6-15-gc40b977e2.20210629 firmware=52.14 ip=192.168.1.170 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11AC
```

Answer (score 1):

It probably means your system does not have the necessary firmware file for the WiFi chip.

Unfortunately, `Comet Lake PCH-LP CNVi WiFi` only indicates that your system has a M.2 CNVio slot for a modern Intel WiFi chip - the actual chip could be one of several models: Wireless-AC 9462, Wireless-AC 9560, or one of the WiFi 6 AX200 or AX210 series chips. The PCI subsystem ID would be necessary for accurate identification. The output of `lspci -d ::0200 -nn` might provide that.

However, `sudo dmesg | grep firmware` might be more immediately useful, revealing a kernel log message that would indicate the name of the missing firmware file. You could then find it in the [linux-firmware Git repository](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/tree/), download it, and place it into `/lib/firmware/` directory on your system.

If your setup uses initramfs, you might or might not need to rebuild it after placing the firmware file; I believe `mkinitcpio` would be the "usual" Arch tool for that, but I'm not very familiar with Arch myself.

Comment: dmesg has this `34.512054] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-hr-b0-72.ucode failed with error -2` so I'm downloading the firmware package. BUT this has only recently gone flaky so it's not that the firmware is missing but that it has become corrupted or knocked out by an update. Make sense? Anyway thanks.

Comment: Perhaps one of those recent updates was a newer kernel, that wants a newer version of the firmware than the previously-used kernel.